# How to filter conversation in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

Please help, I have too much info in Wireshark. I'd like to filter the conversation between the two machines that matter...
There are many many lines displaying almost every packet being exchanged with my machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do a right click in one of the packets I want to follow and then "Conversation Filter">"Ethernet"